# Parsing a huge text file(around 2GB) with custom delimiters

Tags: c#

I have a huge text file around 2GB which I am trying to parse in C#.
The file has custom delimiters for rows and columns. I want to parse the file and extract the data and write to another file by inserting column header and replacing RowDelimiter by newline and ColumnDelimiter by tab so that I can get the data in tabular format.

sample data:
1'~'2'~'3#####11'~'12'~'13

RowDelimiter:  `#####`
ColumnDelimiter:  `'~'`

I keep on getting `System.OutOfMemoryException` on the following line

`while ((line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)`

```
public void ParseFile(string inputfile,string outputfile,string header)
{

    using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(inputfile))
    {
        string line;

        while ((line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputfile))
            {
                //Write the Header row
                sw.Write(header);

                //parse the file
                string[] rows = line.Split(new string[] { ParserConstants.RowSeparator },
                    StringSplitOptions.None);

                foreach (string row in rows)
                {
                    string[] columns = row.Split(new string[] {ParserConstants.ColumnSeparator},
                        StringSplitOptions.None);
                    foreach (string column in columns)
                    {
                        sw.Write(column + "\\t");
                    }
                    sw.Write(ParserConstants.NewlineCharacter);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("File Parsing completed");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One word: CSVHelper.  The size wont matter as it can return an IEnumerable<T>

Comment: If the file has custom delimiters for rows, then `ReadLine` is going to read the entire file into memory.

Comment: I tried using CSVHelper but it keeps failing because my file does not have a default line delimiter

Comment: @DavidG Yes, that is the problem I am facing

Comment: So you're going to have to either read the file character by character looking for the delimiter, or as suggested use CSVHelper and tell it what your delimiter is.

Comment: @PlutonixI tried this reader.Configuration.Delimiter = "'~'"; But did not find a way to set the line delimiter

Comment: Sorry, it doesnt do custom line breaks (which means your file is not standard in any sense of the word).  The author was petitioned for this (issue 768) but declined to change it for reasons of performance.  You will have to use `Peek()` until you see a `#`.  it is configurable in so many many ways, I assumed that was one of them

Comment: Rather than reading one character at a time what you want to do is create a buffer to read a certain amount and then parse that.

Comment: Thanks all for the wonderful comments. This has definitely increased my knowledge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned already in the comments you won't be able to use `ReadLine` to handle this, you'll have to essentially process the data one byte - or character - at a time.  The good news is that this is basically how `ReadLine` works anyway, so we're not losing a lot in this case.

Using a `StreamReader` we can read a series of characters from the source stream (in whatever encoding you need) into an array.  Using that and a `StringBuilder` we can process the stream in chunks and check for separator sequences on the way.

Here's a method that will handle an arbitrary delimiter:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadDelimitedRows(StreamReader reader, string delimiter)
{
    char[] delimChars = delimiter.ToArray();
    int matchCount = 0;
    char[] buffer = new char[512];
    int rc = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while ((rc = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rc; i++)
        {
            char c = buffer[i];
            if (c == delimChars[matchCount])
            {
                if (++matchCount >= delimChars.Length)
                {
                    // found full row delimiter
                    yield return sb.ToString();
                    sb.Clear();
                    matchCount = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (matchCount > 0)
                {
                    // append previously matched portion of the delimiter
                    sb.Append(delimChars.Take(matchCount));
                    matchCount = 0;
                }
                sb.Append(c);
            }
        }
    }
    // return the last row if found
    if (sb.Length > 0)
        yield return sb.ToString();
}
```

This should handle any cases where part of your block delimiter can appear in the actual data.

In order to translate your file from the input format you describe to a simple tab-delimited format you could do something along these lines:

```
const string RowDelimiter = "#####";
const string ColumnDelimiter = "'~'";

using (var reader = new StreamReader(inputFilename))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(File.Create(ouputFilename)))
{
    foreach (var row in ReadDelimitedRows(reader, RowDelimiter))
    {
        writer.Write(row.Replace(ColumnDelimiter, "\t"));
    }
}
```

That should process fairly quickly without eating up too much memory.  Some adjustments might be required for non-ASCII output.

Comment: This almost worked for me except it was chopping off few of the characters of the file in the end

Comment: @Lizzy Oh?  That's odd, it returns all of the last line for me when I test it.  What character encoding does your file use?  Are there any special characters in the last record?  Does it return part of the last record or none of it?

Comment: It returns part of the last row. The sample  last two rows are 37178971'~''~'670748'~'3053242'~'21'~''~'STDLONG'~'NR'~'NR'~'2017-10-21 00:53:54'~''~'NR'~''~'2017-10-21 00:53:54'~'AA+'~''~'Stable'~''~''~''~'Not Rated'~'CreditWatch/Outlook'~'OL'~'2017-10-20 00:00:00'~'274722FH5'~''~'#####37178985'~''~'1233808'~'4314810'~'21'~''~'STDLONG'~'NR'~'NR'~'2017-10-21 00:53:56'~''~'NR'~''~'2017-10-21 00:53:56'~'AA+'~''~'Negative'~''~''~''~'Not Rated'~'CreditWatch/Outlook'~'OL'~'2016-12-01 00:00:00'~'49475BAS7'~''~'#####

Comment: It somehow chops off half of the last row. The result file looks like

37178985  1233808 4314810 21  STDLONG NR NR 2017-10-21 00:53:56  NR  2017-10-21 00:53:56 AA+  Negative    Not Rated CreditWatch/Outlook OL 2016-12-01 00:00:00 49475BAS7   
tch/Outlook OL 2017-10-20 00:00:00 088095R89   
37178971  670748 3053242 21  STDLONG NR NR 2017-10-21 00:53:54  NR  2017-10-21 00:53:54 AA+  Stable    Not Rated CreditWatch/Outlook OL 2017-10-20 00:00:00 274722FH5   
3717

Comment: There are a few non-printables (0x200B and 0x200C - zero-width space and zero-width non-joiner) in that string.  Are they present in the file or just a copy-paste artifact?  After trimming those I get better results.  Also I screwed up the loop - it should be `for (int i = 0; i < rc; i++) {...}` instead.  Will fix.

Comment: @Cory Fixing the loop has fixed the issue. Now I am getting the entire row. Thanks for all your help

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: 4 years later, this answer really helped me out!

Answer (score 1):

Read the data into a buffer and then do your parsing.

```
using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(inputfile))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputfile))
{
    char[] buffer = new char[256];
    int read;

    //Write the Header row
    sw.Write(header);

    string remainder = string.Empty;
    while ((read = rdr.Read(buffer, 0, 256)) > 0)
    {
        string bufferData = new string(buffer, 0, read);
        //parse the file
        string[] rows = bufferData.Split(
            new string[] { ParserConstants.RowSeparator },
            StringSplitOptions.None);

        rows[0] = remainder + rows[0];
        int completeRows = rows.Length - 1;
        remainder = rows.Last();
        foreach (string row in rows.Take(completeRows))
        {
            string[] columns = row.Split(
                new string[] {ParserConstants.ColumnSeparator},
                StringSplitOptions.None);
            foreach (string column in columns)
            {
                sw.Write(column + "\\t");
            }
            sw.Write(ParserConstants.NewlineCharacter);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    if(reamainder.Length > 0)
    {
        string[] columns = remainder.Split(
        new string[] {ParserConstants.ColumnSeparator},
        StringSplitOptions.None);
        foreach (string column in columns)
        {
            sw.Write(column + "\\t");
        }
        sw.Write(ParserConstants.NewlineCharacter);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("File Parsing completed");
}
```

Comment: I suspect that your code might produce unexpected results when the row delimiter string is split across the read boundary.  It looks like you would end up with `rows[0]` containing two rows with separator included.

Comment: @Corery That's what the remainder is for.

Comment: That would work if `remainder` were pre-pended to `bufferData` prior to the `Split`.  As it is now if the row separator string is split between two reads the next operation would add the `remainder`  - the previous row plus the partial separator - into `rows[0]`.  Try it and see.  Put a row separator at offset 254 in the source and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that you are eagerly consuming the whole file and placing it in memory. Attempting to split a 2GB file in memory is going to be problematic, as you now know.

Solution? Consume one lime a time. Because your file doesn't have a standard line separator you'll have to implement a custom parser that does this for you. The following code does just that (or I think it does, I haven't tested it). Its probably very improvable from a performance perspective but it should at least get you started in the right direction (c#7 syntax):

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetRows(string path, string rowSeparator)
{
    bool tryParseSeparator(StreamReader reader, char[] buffer)
    {
        var count = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        if (count != buffer.Length)
            return false;

        return Enumerable.SequenceEqual(buffer, rowSeparator);
    }

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        int peeked;
        var rowBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        var separatorBuffer = new char[rowSeparator.Length];

        while ((peeked = reader.Peek()) > -1)
        {
            if ((char)peeked == rowSeparator[0])
            {
                if (tryParseSeparator(reader, separatorBuffer))
                {
                    yield return rowBuffer.ToString();
                    rowBuffer.Clear();
                }
                else
                {
                    rowBuffer.Append(separatorBuffer);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                rowBuffer.Append((char)reader.Read());
            }
        }

        if (rowBuffer.Length > 0)
            yield return rowBuffer.ToString();
    }
}
```

Now you have a lazy enumeration of rows from your file, and you can process it as you intended to:

```
foreach (var row in GetRows(inputFile, ParserConstants.RowSeparator))
{
     var columns = line.Split(new string[] {ParserConstants.ColumnSeparator},
                              StringSplitOptions.None);
     //etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick...

```
public void ParseFile(string inputfile, string outputfile, string header)
{
    int blockSize = 1024;

    using (var file = File.OpenRead(inputfile))
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputfile))
        {
            int bytes = 0;
            int parsedBytes = 0;
            var buffer = new byte[blockSize];
            string lastRow = string.Empty;

            while ((bytes = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                // Because the buffer edge could split a RowDelimiter, we need to keep the
                // last row from the prior split operation.  Append the new buffer to the
                // last row from the prior loop iteration.
                lastRow += Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer,0, bytes);

                //parse the file
                string[] rows = lastRow.Split(new string[] { ParserConstants.RowSeparator }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                // We cannot process the last row in this set because it may not be a complete
                // row, and tokens could be clipped.
                if (rows.Count() > 1)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count() - 1; i++)
                    {
                        sw.Write(new Regex(ParserConstants.ColumnSeparator).Replace(rows[i], "\t") + ParserConstants.NewlineCharacter);
                    }
                }
                lastRow = rows[rows.Count() - 1];
                parsedBytes += bytes;
                // The following statement is not quite true because we haven't parsed the lastRow.
                Console.WriteLine($"Parsed {parsedBytes.ToString():N0} bytes");
            }
            // Now that there are no more bytes to read, we know that the lastrow is complete.
            sw.Write(new Regex(ParserConstants.ColumnSeparator).Replace(lastRow, "\t"));
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("File Parsing completed.");
}
```

Comment: Not bad, but 1) This will only work for ASCII, 2) you're repeating some code unnecessarily, 3) you can replace the column delimiter in bulk and not get extra tabs in the output and 4) you can split this into smaller general-purpose methods that are easier to reuse later.

Comment: I agree with your comments, however I was trying to keep the code as close to the original as possible and focus on the problem he was trying to solve - reading in a large file.  Optimization and making the code more general purpose was not the question.  While we are on it, I would have used Regex instead of Split, but that is what he had, and was not the problem he was asking about.

Comment: I used to do that a lot, now I just try to write code that I can live with.  And generally I avoid regex solutions unless they are the simplest answer - don't want to give him *two* problems :)

Comment: LOL - I agree.  In his specific case though the regex simplifies the code.  I've updated my post to reflect using regex to parse a row, and now you can see it is a single line of code.  The use of Regex could introduce a problem because the ParserConstants.ColumnSeperator will now be evaluated as a regex string.  Since his ColumnSeperator is simply "'~'", it works fine (I tested it).

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party here, but in case anyone else want to know easy way to load such large CSV file with custom delimiters, [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) does the job for you.

```
using (var parser = new ChoCSVReader("CustomNewLine.csv")
    .WithDelimiter("~")
    .WithEOLDelimiter("#####")
    )
{
    foreach (dynamic x in parser)
        Console.WriteLine(x.DumpAsJson());
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.